# Embedded Prechat custom LWC not creating the Lead record as configured

Tags: lightning-web-components, pre-chat, snap-ins, pre-chat-api

I have created a LWC pre chat custom form and has configured the embedded chat set up to create a Lead record which will be associated to chat transcript. But i dont see a lead record is being created or associated it with chat transcript record. I have not added any special code for creating lead record, thought it will be handled by startChat() function. Below is my JS

```
import { LightningElement, api, track } from 'lwc';
import BasePrechat from 'lightningsnapin/basePrechat';
const PHONE_REGEX = "[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}|[0-9]{10}";
const EMAIL_REGEX= "^[A-Za-z0-9._%!#+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$";


export default class CustomPreChatForm extends BasePrechat {
    @track leadInfo = {};
    @api prechatFields;
    fields;
    namelist;
    errorMessage = '';

    connectedCallback() {
        this.fields = this.prechatFields.map( field => {
            const { label, name, value, required, maxLength } = field;
            return { label, value, name, required, maxLength };
        });
        console.log('fields : ', this.fields);
        this.namelist = this.fields.map( field => field.name );
        console.log('namelist : ', this.namelist);

    }

    handleFieldChange(event){
        this.leadInfo[event.target.name] = event.target.value;
    }

    get getButtonStatus(){
        return !this.errorMessage == '';
    }

    handleStartChat(){   
        // Create an object with pre-chat data
        this.template.querySelectorAll( "lightning-input" ).forEach( input => {
                this.fields[ this.namelist.indexOf( input.name ) ].value = input.value;
        });
        this.fields[ this.namelist.indexOf('Lead_Source__c')].value = 'Marketing';
        this.fields[ this.namelist.indexOf('Marketing_Source__c') ].value = 'Chat';
        console.log('fields 2: ', this.fields);
        if ( this.validateFields( this.fields ).valid ) {
            let checkBool = true;
            for ( let field of this.fields ) {
                console.log( JSON.stringify( field ) );
                console.log( 'Field Value is ' + field.value );
                if ( !field.value ) {
                    checkBool = false;
                    this.errorMessage = 'Please fill ' + field.label + ' to Start the Chat';
                    break;
                }

                if(field.label == 'Phone' && !(new RegExp(PHONE_REGEX).test(field.value))){
                    checkBool = false;
                    this.errorMessage = 'Mobile phone must be in following format: ########## or ###-###-####';
                    break;
                }
                if(field.label == 'Email' && !(new RegExp(EMAIL_REGEX).test(field.value))){
                    checkBool = false;
                    this.errorMessage = 'Please enter a valid email';
                    break;
                }
            }
            if ( checkBool === true ) {
                console.log( 'Starting Chat' );
                this.errorMessage = '';
                this.startChat( this.fields );
            }
        } else {
            console.log( 'Some error in initiating the Chat' );
        }
}
```

Could you please guide me on this, what am i missing here? do i need additional code to search for matching lead record and if not matching create new one. Then. how to link lead record with chat transcript record.